# Teradata: arithmetic operations with INTEGER values

Tags: sql, teradata

Trying to divide one interger value by another. For example:

```
SEL -407302/2823909
```

The result is ZERO O_o

What's that? Decimal values can be divided normally.

Comment: `SEL -407302 * 1.0 / 2823909`

Comment: Your doing integer divison, which will truncate. jarlh's calculation will return a single fractional digit, if you want more you can either multiple by 1.00/1.000/etc. or use a cast: `SEL cast(-407302 as decimal(10,3))/2823909`. Instead of decimal you can also use NUMBER which doesn't need to specify precision.